# Why can I not access my Leiningen dependencies with Clojure code?

Tags: math, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen

In Clojure, if I want to pull in the clojure.inspector functions, I can go like this:

```
(use `[clojure.math.numeric-tower :include (expt)])
```

From the REPL, and I can now evaluate the function expt.

However, it seems to me that there should be (and probably is) another way to do it - pulling in the code using Leiningen dependencies.

I add this line to my project.clj:

```
[org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.2"]
```

And I restart the REPL to pull in the new dependency. I even do "lein deps" to be safe (there is no output for that command). When I try to evaluate expt, it gives me a RuntimeException, and says its Unable to resolve the symbol.

How can I access the expt function, only using Leiningen dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. It doesn't work like that. Adding a dependency puts the code on your *classpath*, which merely means it is available for you to use. In order to actually use the things inside the namespaces, you need to use

```
(require '[the-namespace :refer [the things you want to use]])
```

or

```
(require '[the-namespace :as tn])
(tn/somevar)
```

or do either of those things in an ns declaration (when not in the REPL and working with a file)

```
(ns foo
  (:require [the-namespace :as tn]))
```